# How to get a QModelIndex from another QSqlQuery used for searching the database (needed for selecting the found items)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtsql, qmodelindex

I have a problem when dealing with my QSqlQueryModel. I want to search the database for some items and select them in my QTableView with QItemSelectionModel which needs a QModelIndex.

What I don't understand is how should I search in order to get the corresponding QModelIndex for my model/view architecture.
I can't possibly use the model itself, because it would mess up the items shown in the view. So a QSqlQuery or an extra QSqlQueryModel would maybe be an option, but how is it possible to translate from their result-index (.at()?) to a QModelIndex which fits to my Model/View-System...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to take a look at [QSQLQueryModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquerymodel.html), and set your TableView's model to it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but it's not very useful.


I am already using QSqlQueryModel for my QTableView and it is naturally set to my QTableView. It is also working fine, but now I need to search in the Database without changing the QSqlQueryModel, because it should only highlight (->QItemSelectionModel) the found items.

So my plan was to search in another QSqlQueryModel? or a QSqlQuery. 


Again my question:
How is it possible to get a QModelIndex of a (for example) QSqlResult, which I got from my QSqlQuery?


It could be a "reverse"-function of indexInQuery(), any ideas?